# centering a button background image inside a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have managed to get the button image in place correctly but now the positioning is all off.

I want it to be centered as this image shows:

[image]

What I have so far is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/snjCu.

I am trying to position the image inside the center of its column so that it is correctly in place when the screen is larger.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<footer>
        <div class="banner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="footer-controls" class="text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
                <span>GALLERY</span>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="orange-button"></a>
                </div>
             <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <span>LEGAL</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

footer #footer-controls .orange-button {
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/lmB72tf.png') no-repeat;
width: 215px;
height: 210px;
background-size: 100%;
position: absolute;;
top: -50px
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/effef47b6bca698d07eb try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the position of the image with a CSS transform

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BJqgp)

```
footer #footer-controls .orange-button {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/lmB72tf.png') no-repeat;
  width: 215px;
  height: 210px;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left:50%; /* push the image half-way over */
  transform:translateX(-50%); /* bring it back half its own width */
  /* or margin-left: -50% of image width */ 
}
```

Comment: that works pretty well, is there any limitations to browser support with transforms?

Comment: IE9 and up ( http://caniuse.com/transforms2d ) but if you're using feature detection the alternative `negative margin` works in all. However, it does require you to know the size of the image which a transform does not.

Answer (score 0):

Although not desirable, I've found that giving the *column* and the *orange-button* fixed `width` styles will solve this issue.

```
.orange-button {
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lmB72tf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 215px 210px;
display:inline-block;
width: 215px;
height: 210px;
```

Comment: can you explain please? I would like the column to remain the width bootstrap has set it to so that it adjusts on screens properly.

Comment: just tried this, it destroys the footer and expands it :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can center background images with:
background-position: center center;
This is actually the default value.

However your container with the image is not centered. 
You may wanna consider repositioning the container and trying somthing else than 
position: absolute;

Comment: can you offer an alternative?